# MVC - Redirect to specific page when trying to acess invalid url

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to redirect to a specific page if the user try to access an invalid url?
Example: Redirect to "http://localhost/Home" if the user try to access "http://localhost/InvalidControllerName".

Comment: You can specify custom error pages: http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

Answer (score 0):

Add ErrorControllers or static page to with 404 error information.

Modify you web.config (in case of controller).

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Errors/Error404" />
</customErrors>
```

Or in case of static page

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Static404.html" />
</customErrors>
```

This will handle both missed routes and missed actions.